# MouseClick event on PictureBox trigger corresponding CheckBox

Tags: c#, winforms

My C# window forms application generate a list of CheckBox and PictureBox (in pair) at runtime. I want it so that when I click on the PictureBox (i.e. a MouseClick event), the corresponding CheckBox is checked/unchecked. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to store pointer for corresponding checkbox in `Tag` property of `PictureBox`. After that, you can use it in PictureBox click event handler:

```
((sender as PictureBox).Tag as CheckBox).Checked = !((sender as PictureBox).Tag as CheckBox);
```

Don't forget to check `Tag` for `null`

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the controls on the fly, I would prefer building an associated dictionary to store the pairs rather than using Tag.

```
Dictionary<PictureBox, CheckBox> association = new Dictionary<PictureBox, CheckBox>();

// ---------------------------------------
// then, in your generation code

PictureBox pb = // init
CheckBox cb = // init

// whatever

association.Add(pb, cb);

// ---------------------------------------    
// then, in your click handler for picturebox

PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
CheckBox cb = association[pb];

cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
```